# How to model this correlated subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

So this query returns this table

```
select * from players where username = 'weise03'

reportID username ign
992499   weise03  Weisey
992637   weise03  Weisey
```

Using the reportID from this query I can run

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reportID = 992499
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reportID = 992637


reportID username ign
992499   alphaas  Jester <-- I want this

reportID username   ign
992637   PorcoDiooo Cotton Mather <-- and this
```

I hoped I could've done something along the lines of

```
    SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT reportID
    FROM players
    WHERE username = 'weise03'
) AS t
JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM reports
    WHERE reportID = t.reportID
) AS x ON t.reportID = x.reportID;
```

But found out you can't use aliases in subqueries like this so that's out.

I realize I could run a query for each reportID returned from the first query but I'm wondering if there's a better way to model this. If there is no better way how could I make it as fast as possible ***without adding an extra field*** since some commands in the future may require hundreds of queries.

Comment: whats your desired output?

Comment: I marked the 2 lines I want with <-- I want this and <-- and this in the second code block

Comment: From what? Your sample data isn't complete. Kindly share sample data from both tables along with desired output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a join

```
select r.* from reports r 
join players p on p.reportid = r.reportid
where p.username = 'weise03'
```

Comment: I realized now I should clear this up. The command I want to run only takes in the username so the reportID has to be derived from a query and I can't join on reportID like that :/

Comment: Actually that first one did work. I was sure I couldn't do something like that after messing around but boy did you prove me wrong.